# Curl download request from multiple client devices to a single server machine

Tags: curl, https

I need to download a single file from a single linux server machine using the curl commands running in multiple devices in parallel.

curl command uses https request to download the file https://ipaddress:portno. The downloading is happening one by one even though the commands are running parallelly executing from all the devices. curl command from a device results 0kb download till another devices complete the file download and the next device will initiate the download. How do I make this parallel like all the devices should download the files simultaneously.

Comment: That is not a problem of curl but of the used server. Use a http server that supports proper multi-threading or multi-process.